# Navigate to the Map from the Start Center or List View?

Tags: maximo

Maximo 7.6.1.1/Spatial 7.6.0.5:

---

Scenario:

A user wants to go directly to the map to explore **multiple** assets, locations, WOs, or SRs.

- The user does not have a specific asset/location/WO/SR that they want to explore. They only know the general area that assets/locations/WOs/SRs are located in.

---

In the Assets example, the only OOB way to do this is to:

1. Go to the Assets application.
2. In the List View, do a filter to show GIS assets.
3. **Click a random GIS asset** (likely not located in the part of the map that the user wants to explore).
4. Click the map tab.
5. Manually pan/zoom to the area in question.

---

Is there a way to navigate to the Map **directly** from the Start Center or List View (instead of navigating to a random single record as mentioned above)?

*Even a simple **hyperlink on the Start Center** that points to a generic asset/location/WO/SR would be an improvement over the single-record-workaround mentioned above.*

<sup>*Keyword: Maximo Spatial*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Hyperlinks on the **Start Center** might work, but they also might be misleading:

> Map shortcuts to specific/sample records:
>
> - [Town Hall (a specific Location)](http://%3Cyour%20host%3E/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?&forcereload=true&additionalevent=useqbe&additionaleventvalue=location=%27M001%27&changetab=mxmap&event=loadapp&value=location)
> - [Main St (a specific Asset)](http://%3Cyour%20host%3E/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?&forcereload=true&additionalevent=useqbe&additionaleventvalue=assetnum=%27RD-305220%27&changetab=mxmap&event=loadapp&value=asset)
> - [WO at Town Hall (closed/not editable)](http://%3Cyour%20host%3E/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?&forcereload=true&additionalevent=useqbe&additionaleventvalue=wonum=%27WO2492%27&changetab=mxmap&event=loadapp&value=wotrack)
> - [SR at Town Hall (resolved/not editable)](http://%3Cyour%20host%3E/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?&forcereload=true&additionalevent=useqbe&additionaleventvalue=ticketid=%27SR1627%27&changetab=mxmap&event=loadapp&value=sr)

```
http://<your host>/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?&forcereload=true&additionalevent=useqbe&additionaleventvalue=location=%27M001%27&changetab=mxmap&event=loadapp&value=location

http://<your host>/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?&forcereload=true&additionalevent=useqbe&additionaleventvalue=assetnum=%27RD-305220%27&changetab=mxmap&event=loadapp&value=asset

http://<your host>/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?&forcereload=true&additionalevent=useqbe&additionaleventvalue=wonum=%27WO2492%27&changetab=mxmap&event=loadapp&value=wotrack

http://<your host>/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?&forcereload=true&additionalevent=useqbe&additionaleventvalue=ticketid=%27SR1627%27&changetab=mxmap&event=loadapp&value=sr
```

Possibly helpful: [Creating a Hyperlink on the Start Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/creating-hyperlink-start-center)

Answer (score 1):

There is a System Property in Maximo that allows you to enable the tabs to display without opening a record.  Set the System Property mxe.webclient.tabBreadCrumbs  to 0 and perform a live refresh.  Now click on a Favorite Application from your Start Center and you will see that the tabs are displayed without opening a record.  You can simply click on the Map tab.  I recommend using a Geocode Service such as a street intersection to allow a user to quickly navigate to an area of the map.

[Asset application with Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceJDb.png)